# Why does .SD in a data.table non-equi join throws an error occasionally?

Tags: r, data.table

I have noticed an inconsistency when using `.SD` in a non-equi join. 
Is there an explanation for this?

Depending on the "direction" or "type" of join, using `j = .SD` throws an error.

```
library(data.table)
d1 <- fread("a, b
            1, 11
            6, 16")
d2 <- data.table(r = 1:5, s = seq(0, 20, 5))

d1
```

> ```
>    a  b
> 1: 1 11
> 2: 6 16
> ```

```
d2
```

> ```
>    r  s
> 1: 1  0
> 2: 2  5
> 3: 3 10
> 4: 4 15
> 5: 5 20
> ```

```
d1[d2, on = .(a <= s, b >= s)]
```

> ```
>     a  b r
> 1:  0  0 1
> 2:  5  5 2
> 3: 10 10 3
> 4: 10 10 3
> 5: 15 15 4
> 6: 20 20 5
> ```

```
d1[d2, on = .(a <= s, b >= s), j = .SD]
```

> Error in `[.data.table`(d1, d2, on = .(a <= s, b >= s), j = .SD) :
>   column(s) not found: a

```
d2[d1, on = .(s >= a, s <= b)]
```

> ```
>    r s s.1
> 1: 2 1  11
> 2: 3 1  11
> 3: 3 6  16
> 4: 4 6  16
> ```

```
d2[d1, on = .(s >= a, s <= b), j = .SD]
```

> ```
>    r s
> 1: 2 1
> 2: 3 1
> 3: 3 6
> 4: 4 6
> ```

I have reproduced the behaviour with R version 3.6.0 and `data.table` versions 1.11.8, 1.12.2, and 1.12.3 (development version on github).

I am aware that there are related discussions on github, e.g.,  [Both columns for rolling and non-equi joins #3093](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/pull/3093), [.SD in expression with j? #3115](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/3115) but I haven't found (perhaps overlooked?) an explanation for the observed behaviour there.

Comment: Re "explanation for observed behavior" -- a bug, I would guess. There are several open issues about how things are added or removed from .SD (eg, by get and mget). Maybe file the one that throws an error as a new bug? I couldn't find it in the issues list. (Sort of close, maybe: https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/1989)

Comment: @Frank, thank you. I have filed an issue report https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/3635.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Arun and Matt, the [issue](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/3635) has been [fixed (note item 24)](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/blob/master/NEWS.md#bug-fixes) with the latest development version of `data.table` 1.12.3.

So,

```
d1[d2, on = .(a <= s, b >= s), j = .SD]
```

no longer throws an error but returns

> ```
>     a  b
> 1:  0  0
> 2:  5  5
> 3: 10 10
> 4: 10 10
> 5: 15 15
> 6: 20 20
> ```

as expected.